# Jagged Uint8 array convert to C# byte

Tags: c#, c++, byte, jagged-arrays, uint

I have a jagged `uint8` array like this in c++:

```
UINT8 ras[2][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```

I need some way to use this as a byte array in c#.
Something like

```
byte[2][3] ras = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```

I have a lot of `uint8` arrays, so doing it manually is not an option.
Anya ideas?

Comment: C# supports jagged arrays well.  What is completely unclear is how you intend to interop with your C++ code.  File?  COM?  pinvoke?  C++/CLI?

Comment: I have c++ files containing the jagged UINT8 arrays. I need these converted to c# jagged byte arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the comments to your question above, you are simply missing a bit of C# syntax.

The C# syntax would be:

```
byte[][] ras = new byte[][] {new byte[] {1,2,3}, new byte[] {4,5,6}};
```

It's quite a bit more verbose than the equivalent c++, but easily translated mechanically with sed.